# Review of PCB RF Design

Tags: pcb-design, rf, radio, pcb-layers, nrf24l01

I designed a 4 layer RF board with the NRF24L01+. When I got the boards in to test I was not able to establish a radio link with some other NRF24L01+ modules. I have attached my schematic and board layout for review, but have already identified a few improvements.

[image]
[image]

1. Update track width from 0.165mm to 0.19mm for 50Ohm impedance matching (Using PCBWay 4 Layer)
2. Replace resonator with crystal. I thought I could save BOM count by using a resonator, and looking at my oscilloscope, I only see a little amplitude difference between the resonator and crystal.
3. Add more capacitors to the 3.3V rail.
4. Keep the trace length less than 5.79mm

This is my first RF design, and am wondering if there are any other updates I should make to the schematic or layout, or if the design changes I have already listed are not necessary.

I would also like to confirm that the layer stackup is correct. As designed it should be:

1. Signal
2. Power
3. GND
4. Signal

What is the best way to test that the internal 3rd layer is GND?

Comment: Please show the other layers' layouts too.

Comment: Did you review the section "PCB layout and decoupling guidelines" in the datasheet?  Also in the datasheet are example PCB layouts. Last (but not least) if you had to do this over again it might be best to consider using a readily available NRF24L01 PCB module then just include an interface for the data pins.

Comment: Integreate the large GND pad below the chip body into the GND routing and place some vias there like the referece design in the datasheet shows it.